# How to test the integrity of hardware on aws instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cpu, hardware

I have a cluster of consumers (50 or so instance) consuming from kafka partitions.

I notice that there is this one server that is consistently slow. Its cpu usage is always around 80-100%. While the other partitions is around 50%.

Originally I thought there is a slight chance that this is traffic dependent, so I manually switch the partitions that the slow loader is consuming.

However I did not observe an increase in processing speed.

I also don't see cpu steal from `iostat`, but since all consumer is running the same code I suspect there is some bottle neck in the hardware.

Unfortunately, I can't just replace the server unless I can provide conclusive proof that the hardware is the problem.

So I want to write a load testing script that pin point the bottle neck.

My plan is to write a while loop in python that does n computations, and find out what is the max computation that the slow consumer can do and what is the max computation that the fast consumer can do.

What other testing strategy can I do?

Perhaps I should test disk bottle neck by having my python script write to txt file?

Here is fast consumer `iostat`

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          50.01    0.00    3.96    0.13    0.12   45.77

Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
xvda              1.06         0.16        11.46     422953   30331733
xvdb            377.63         0.01     46937.99      35897 124281808572
xvdc            373.43         0.01     46648.25      26603 123514631628
md0             762.53         0.01     93586.24      22235 247796440032
```

Here is slow consumer iostat

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          81.58    0.00    5.28    0.11    0.06   12.98

Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
xvda              1.02         0.40        13.74     371145   12685265
xvdb            332.85         0.02     40775.06      18229 37636091096
xvdc            327.42         0.01     40514.44      10899 37395540132
md0             676.47         0.01     81289.50      11287 75031631060
```

Comment: I'm very confused as to why you'd waste time on this.  To me one of the points of having cloud based hosting is that you can "throw away" an instance at any time and spin up a new one.

Comment: Stop the instance, and start it again.  You will then be on different hardware, as was [mentioned yesterday](https://serverfault.com/q/912752/153161).   EC2 returns the underlying hardware allocation to the pool when you stop an instance.  Starting it again will never (for all practical purposes) result in the same hardware being reallocated to the same instance.